# When is it okay to leave out SPF-records?

Tags: email, smtp, spf

I am trying to help out a little non-profit organization, who has decided to let One.com host their domain, including website and e-mail. Now, my issue is that One.com does not add SPF-records or DKIM-keys to your domain and I believe that is the reason why a large number of mails sent from the domain, end up in spam.

I've been in touch with their support, who kindly answered:

> You are already using our mail servers, there is no need to use SPF for that.
>
> Our mail servers already have SPF installed, and if you are using our mail servers, SPF will not be question since domain is hosted here and it is using One.com's mail server. SPF will only be required if your domain is hosted here but is using a different MX record or mail server

I've tried to figure out if you can leave out SPF, but all I've been able to conclude is that proper SPF on each domain is definitely the proper way, instead of just the hosting companys main domain. I mean, if it was that simple, how come even Google Apps, Zoho, Rackspace etc. recommends adding SPF, if it worked just as well leaving it out - you'd be using their MX as well, so isn't that the same? And wouldn't leaving SPF out leave us with the same issues as before SPF, namedly that you'd have no way to validate if mail was truly being sent from the owners of the domain or just somebody imposing.

So what it comes down to: Can One.com really leave out SPF records on their clients domains, send mail on the clients behalfs and still expect mail to come through without ending up in spam more often?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No, they can't".  The longer answer is a little more complicated.

SPF uses either the EHLO domain of the sending server or the domain in the Return-Path to look up SPF records in DNS.  Most systems that handle multiple domains do not use SPF records on the EHLO domains of the sending servers, so the SPF domain is taken from the email's Return-Path.  You should take a look at the Return-Path for one of the emails that this non-profit has sent through One.com to determine whether the Return-Path is on a subdomain of one.com, or is using the non-profit's domain.  The latter is definitely preferred.

If the Return-Path is on a subdomain of one.com, then that's the domain that will be used to look up SPF records.  So adding SPF records to your non-profit's DNS won't do anything.  While this may seem the easier path, it causes problems with DMARC and may cause the email to be flagged as spam even if it passes SPF, as the address in the 'From' header will have a domain that doesn't match the Return-Path

If the Return-Path is on a subdomain of your non-profit's domain, then you should definitely add an SPF record to your non-profit's DNS.  Looking at one.com's current records, something like:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.one.com ~all
```

should do it.

By the way, you should be able to see whether an email has been SPF or DKIM authorized by looking at the headers of the received email.  That's the best way to understand the actual behavior.